# Function not getting called with protocol delegate and view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols

I needed to delegate an click action for my `UIView` class to my `UIViewController` class since swift does not support multiple class inheritance. So i wanted it such that once a button is clicked on my subview, a function in my `ViewController` class is called. Am using `protocol delegate` to achieve this but on the click of my button it does not work for me as the function does not get called. Please help me out. Code snippet would be largely appreciated.

**ViewController**

```
 var categoryItem: CategoryItem! = CategoryItem() //Category Item
 private func setupExplore() {
//assign delegate of category item to controller
self.categoryItem.delegate = self
      }
//function to be called
extension BrowseViewController: ExploreDelegate {
    func categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory) {
        print("clicked")
        let categoryView = ProductByCategoryView()
        categoryView.category = category
        categoryView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryView, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**Explore.swift (subview)**

```
    import UIKit

    protocol ExploreDelegate:UIViewController {
        func categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory)
    }

    class Explore: UIView {
 var delegate: ExploreDelegate?

    class CategoryItem: UIView {
    var delegate: ExploreDelegate?
    var category: ProductCategory? {
        didSet {
            self.configure()
        }
    }
    var tapped: ((_ category: ProductCategory?) -> Void)?

    func configure() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.categoryTapped)))
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @objc func categoryTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory.everything)
        self.tapped?(self.category)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you assigned the delegate in the controller?

Comment: whats relation between BrowseViewController and Explore or CategoryItem

Comment: You cannot have a global property for your delegate, it needs to be a property of some object, in your case `CategoryItem`. And then you need to set the delegate to an instance of `BrowseViewController`.

Comment: @PGDev I just updated my code showing how am assigning my .xib delegate in my controller class

Comment: @jawadAli Explore is my .xib file which am rendering inside my BrowseViewController.  CategoryItem is just a UI class for my button.

Comment: @koen please review my code. I just set my delegate to CategoryItem class and removed the global property

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: same result. function not getting called

Comment: So `categoryTapped` is called, but `categoryClicked` is not?

Comment: yes. that's the case

Comment: do you know where am getting it wrong?

Comment: let c  = CategoryItem(). c.delegate =self

Comment: @AdemÖzsayın not working